# Render HTML Tag attribute using mustache

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

In my mustache template I do have something like:

```
<div {{attr}}="{{attrVal}}"></div>
```

Rendering this using

```
Mustache.render(template, {attr : 'data-test', attrVal : 'test'})
```

does produce

```
<div ="test"></div>
```

I expect to get something like

```
<div data-test="test"></div>
```

Isn't it possible to render attribute name inside of a tag using Mustache?

**UPDATE**

I figured out the problem. I define my HTML Mustache Templates inside custom `<template>` tags in my document. For example:

```
<template id='myTemplate'>
    <div {{dataAttr}}="{{dataAttrValue}}"></div>
</template>
```

When getting the template using `document.querySelector("#myTemplate").innerHTML` the browser does convert the `{{dataAttr}}` to `{{dataattr}}` because attributes are case insensitiv. So calling

```
Mustache.render(
    document.querySelector("#myTemplate").innerHTML, 
    { dataAttr : 'data-attr', dataAttrValue : 'test'}
);
```

Results in

```
<div ="test"></div>
```

Comment: What you're doing there actually looks correct. As an example, check out: http://jsbin.com/rilihasise/1/edit?html,js,console Is it possible `template` isn't defined properly?

Comment: You are right. Regarding mustache it was correct. The error was caused because of something else (see edited question above). But nevertheless your answer helped me figured out the problem.

Comment: To prevent HTML parser to interpret your templates as HTML (as they are not) you'd better use `<script>` element, for example as `<script type='text/template' id='myTemplate'>...</script>`

Comment: Thats a good hint. My Application is a Polymer based web application. Inside a polymer Elements HTML `<template>` tags are used to define HTML in conjunction with data binding expressions which have slightly the same syntax using `{{}}`. So for consistency I decided to put mustache HTML templates inside a `<template>` tag.

Comment: By WebComponents specification `<template>` is valid HTML element - its content gets parsed into [shadow] DOM, etc. But this `<div {{dataAttr}}=...` of yours is not valid HTML construct so is the problem...

Comment: I redesigned my component structure so currently I don't need Mustache but rather use polymers data binding in template HTML. Also `<div {{dataAttr}}=...` isn't used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code snippet will help you..

```js
var template = document.querySelector("#template").innerHTML;
//Mustache.parse(template); // optional, speeds up future uses
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {
  attr: "data-test",
  attrVal: "test"
});
document.querySelector("#target").innerHTML = rendered;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.1/mustache.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="target">Loading...</div>
  <template id="template" >
    <textarea style="width:300px">
      <div {{attr}}="{{attrVal}}"></div>
    </textarea>
  </template>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I head the same problem Try the single [']:

```
<template id='myTemplate'>
    <div {{dataAttr}}='{{dataAttrValue}}'></div>
</template>
```

.....

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using **to_html** method for the expected output.

```
const HTML = Mustache.to_html(template, {attr : 'data-test', attrVal : 'test'});

document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML = HTML;
```

```js
const template = `
 <div {{attr}}="{{attrVal}}">
 </div>
`

const HTML = Mustache.to_html(template, {attr : 'data-test', attrVal : 'test'});

document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML = HTML;

console.log(document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <template id='myTemplate'>
    </template>
    <div id="display-output"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.1.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```